# Как сделать 2 кнопки в одном ряду, если кнопки берутся из массива, telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Имеется код со списком городов

```py
city_list = [' Абакан', 
' Арзамас',
' Артем', 
' Астрахань', 
' Балашиха', 
' Батайск']
```

И имеется код который создаёт кнопки:

```py
def city_but():
    city_but = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True)
    for city in city_list:
        city_but.add(
            city
        )
    city_but.add(
        " Главное меню"
    )
    return city_but
```

В `row_width` стоит значение 2,по идее должно быть 2 кнопки в одном ряду, но всё равно каждая кнопка в разных рядах, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

1. Создайте пустой список - `keys = []` для хранения кнопок клавиатуры
2. В цикле добавляйте в список экземпляр `KeyboardButton`
3. используйте `*keys` в `city_but.add` для добавления все созданных экземпляров кнопок

Итоговый код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    city_list = [' Абакан',
                 ' Арзамас',
                 ' Артем',
                 ' Астрахань',
                 ' Балашиха',
                 ' Батайск']

    city_but = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True)
    keys = []
    for city in city_list:
        keys.append(types.KeyboardButton(city))
    city_but.add(*keys,types.KeyboardButton(" Главное меню"))

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет!', reply_markup=city_but)
```